# Netty: IllegalReferenceCountException issue in Netty 4.0.14?

Tags: netty

Hi I am very new to Netty, as I just recently took over the netty customization project from a colleague. Sorry if this has been asked before (I did search already). Our Netty version is `4.0.14`.

I keep getting `IllegalReferenceCountException` on a tiny subset of my calls to `channel.writeAndFlush(response);`

So I added some debug printout in Netty, and it seems that for the same call to writeAndFlush netty may release the (ByteBuf)response.content() multiple times. Is this a known issue that is already fixed after 4.0.14, or am I using it wrong?

My debug print out below. There are four times that the ByteBuf's retain/release is called.

Release `(refCnt 1->0)` followed by a Retain `(refCnt 0->1)`, then a release `(1->0)` and a release `(0->-1)`:

> **1 -> 0** | io.netty.buffer.AbstractReferenceCountedByteBuf.release 142 |
> io.netty.handler.codec.http.DefaultFullHttpResponse.release 79 |
> io.netty.util.ReferenceCountUtil.release 68 |
> io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageEncoder.write 91 |
> io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageCodec.write 116 |
> io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite 645 |
> io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.write 699 |
> io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.write 638 |
> io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.write 265 |
> io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite 645 |
> io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.access$2000 29 |
> io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext$WriteTask.run 906 |
> io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks 354 |
> io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run 353 |
> io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run 101 |
> java.lang.Thread.run 745
>
> **0 -> 1**  | io.netty.buffer.AbstractReferenceCountedByteBuf.retain 99 |
> io.netty.buffer.CompositeByteBuf.retain 1570 |
> io.netty.buffer.CompositeByteBuf.retain 40 |
> io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpObjectEncoder.encodeAndRetain 165 |
> io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpObjectEncoder.encode 92 |
> io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageEncoder.write 89 |
> io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.write 193 |
> io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite 645 |
> io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.write 699 |
> io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.write 638 |
> io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageEncoder.write 115 |
> io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageCodec.write 116 |
> io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite 645 |
> io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.write 699 |
> io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.write 638 |
> io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.write 265 |
> io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite 645 |
> io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.access$2000 29 |
> io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext$WriteTask.run 906 |
> io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks 354 |
> io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run 353 |
> io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run 101 |
> java.lang.Thread.run 745
>
> **1 -> 0**  | io.netty.buffer.AbstractReferenceCountedByteBuf.release 142
> | io.netty.handler.codec.http.DefaultFullHttpResponse.release 79 |
> io.netty.util.ReferenceCountUtil.release 68 |
> io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageEncoder.write 91 |
> io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.write 193 |
> io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite 645 |
> io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.write 699 |
> io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.write 638 |
> io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageEncoder.write 115 |
> io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageCodec.write 116 |
> io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite 645 |
> io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.write 699 |
> io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.write 638 |
> io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.write 265 |
> io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite 645 |
> io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.access$2000 29 |
> io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext$WriteTask.run 906 |
> io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks 354 |
> io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run 353 |
> io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run 101 |
> java.lang.Thread.run 745
>
> **0 -> -1**  | io.netty.buffer.AbstractReferenceCountedByteBuf.release 142
> | io.netty.util.ReferenceCountUtil.release 68 |
> io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundBuffer.safeRelease 509 |
> io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundBuffer.remove 294 |
> io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundBuffer.failFlushed 448 |
> io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush0 684 |
> io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.flush0 271 |
> io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush 651 |
> io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadHandler.flush 1038 |
> io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush 675 |
> io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.flush 656 |
> io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.flush 115 |
> io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.flush 198 |
> io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush 675 |
> io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.flush 656 |
> io.netty.channel.ChannelDuplexHandler.flush 117 |
> io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush 675 |
> io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.flush 656 |
> io.netty.channel.ChannelDuplexHandler.flush 117 |
> io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush 675 |
> io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.access$1600 29 |
> io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext$WriteTask.run 908 |
> io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks 354 |
> io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run 353 |
> io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run 101 |
> java.lang.Thread.run 745

Comment: try looking through this : http://netty.io/wiki/reference-counted-objects.html#wiki-h2-10